# How can one be able to solve incompatible type in firebase recycler view

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am trying to retrieve my data from the firebase but I am getting this error, I don't know how to solve it.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.elijah.ukeme.ecommerceapp, PID: 9835
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type model.DeliveredOrder
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:436)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:29)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:15)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseCachingSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(BaseCachingSnapshotParser.java:36)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:52)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:108)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:148)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4578)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3080)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2590)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

This is the activity to retrieve the data:

```
public class DeliveredListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference deliveredOrderRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_delivered_list);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_delivered_order_list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        deliveredOrderRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Delivered List");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DeliveredOrder> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DeliveredOrder>()
                .setQuery(deliveredOrderRef,DeliveredOrder.class)
                .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DeliveredOrder, DeliveredViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DeliveredOrder, DeliveredViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DeliveredViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull DeliveredOrder model) {

                holder.shipperName.setText("Name: "+model.getName());
                holder.phoneNumber.setText("Phone Number "+model.getPhone());
                holder.receiver.setText("Received By: "+model.getReceiversName());
                holder.totalPrice.setText("Total Price: "+model.getTotalAmount());
                holder.addressCity.setText("Address: "+model.getAddress()+", "+model.getCity());
                holder.dateTime.setText("Ordered On: "+model.getOrderedDate()+" at "+model.getOrderedTime());
                holder.dateTime2.setText("Received On: "+model.getDeliveredDate()+" at "+model.getDeliveredTime());

                holder.deliveredProductBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String Uid = getRef(position).getKey();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(DeliveredListActivity.this, AdminUserProductActivtity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("uid",Uid);
                        intent.putExtra("route","Admin");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public DeliveredViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.delivered_order_layout,parent,false);

                return new DeliveredViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }
}
```

This is my model class:

```
public class DeliveredOrder {

    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String totalAmount;
    private String orderedDate;
    private String orderedTime;
    private String deliveredDate;
    private String deliveredTime;
    private String receiversName;

    public DeliveredOrder() {
    }

    public DeliveredOrder(String name, String phone, String address, String city, String totalAmount, String orderedDate, String orderedTime, String deliveredDate, String deliveredTime, String receiversName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
        this.orderedDate = orderedDate;
        this.orderedTime = orderedTime;
        this.deliveredDate = deliveredDate;
        this.deliveredTime = deliveredTime;
        this.receiversName = receiversName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getTotalAmount() {
        return totalAmount;
    }

    public void setTotalAmount(String totalAmount) {
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
    }

    public String getOrderedDate() {
        return orderedDate;
    }

    public void setOrderedDate(String orderedDate) {
        this.orderedDate = orderedDate;
    }

    public String getOrderedTime() {
        return orderedTime;
    }

    public void setOrderedTime(String orderedTime) {
        this.orderedTime = orderedTime;
    }

    public String getDeliveredDate() {
        return deliveredDate;
    }

    public void setDeliveredDate(String deliveredDate) {
        this.deliveredDate = deliveredDate;
    }

    public String getDeliveredTime() {
        return deliveredTime;
    }

    public void setDeliveredTime(String deliveredTime) {
        this.deliveredTime = deliveredTime;
    }

    public String getReceiversName() {
        return receiversName;
    }

    public void setReceiversName(String receiversName) {
        this.receiversName = receiversName;
    }
}
```

This is the viewHoder class:

```
public class DeliveredViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView shipperName, phoneNumber,totalPrice,addressCity,dateTime,dateTime2,receiver;
    public Button deliveredProductBtn;
    public DeliveredViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        shipperName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delivered_order_user_name);
        phoneNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delivered_order_phone_number);
        totalPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delivered_order_total_price);
        addressCity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delivered_order_address_and_city);
        dateTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ordered_date_and_time);
        dateTime2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delivered_order_date_and_time);
        receiver = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receivers_name_textview);
        deliveredProductBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_show_all_products_delivered);
    }
}
```

This is the database:

```
{
  "Admin" : {
    "08167988220" : {
      "name" : "Elijah Ukeme",
      "password" : "adminmet",
      "phone" : "08167988220"
    }
  },
  "Cart List" : {
    "Admin View" : {
      "08167988220" : {
        "Products" : {
          "10 Mar, 202217:07:43 &" : {
            "date" : "13 Mar, 2022",
            "discount" : "",
            "pid" : "10 Mar, 202217:07:43 &",
            "pname" : "Cap",
            "price" : "2000",
            "quantity" : "1",
            "time" : "12:56:00 &"
          },
          "12 Mar, 202214:01:56 &" : {
            "date" : "12 Mar, 2022",
            "discount" : "",
            "pid" : "12 Mar, 202214:01:56 &",
            "pname" : "Wristwatch",
            "price" : "5000",
            "quantity" : "1",
            "time" : "14:12:44 &"
          },
          "12 Mar, 202214:04:16 &" : {
            "date" : "12 Mar, 2022",
            "discount" : "",
            "pid" : "12 Mar, 202214:04:16 &",
            "pname" : "Headset",
            "price" : "2000",
            "quantity" : "3",
            "time" : "14:13:36 &"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "User View" : {
      "08167988220" : {
        "Products" : {
          "10 Mar, 202217:07:43 &" : {
            "date" : "13 Mar, 2022",
            "discount" : "",
            "pid" : "10 Mar, 202217:07:43 &",
            "pname" : "Cap",
            "price" : "2000",
            "quantity" : "1",
            "time" : "12:56:00 &"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Delivered List" : {
    "address" : "New Airport",
    "city" : "Calabar",
    "deliveredDate" : "14 Mar, 2022",
    "deliveredTime" : "13:11:15 ",
    "name" : "Elijah Ukeme",
    "orderedDate" : "12 Mar, 2022",
    "orderedTime" : "14:14:29 ",
    "phone" : "08167988220",
    "receiversName" : "Joy Elijah",
    "totalAmount" : "15000"
  },
  "Products" : {
    "10 Mar, 202217:07:43 &" : {
      "category" : "hatsCap",
      "date" : "10 Mar, 2022",
      "description" : "Cool Baby Cap",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecommerce-app-c7f6b.appspot.com/o/Product%20Images%2Fimage%3A1253310%20Mar%2C%20202217%3A07%3A43%20%26.jpg?alt=media&token=c7d241b0-89c2-40d8-8971-6a9d38ec9ad2",
      "pid" : "10 Mar, 202217:07:43 &",
      "price" : "2000",
      "productStatus" : "Approved",
      "product_name" : "Cap",
      "sellerAddress" : "New Airport",
      "sellerEmail" : "elijah@gmail.com",
      "sellerName" : "Elijah Ukeme",
      "sellerPhone" : "08167988220",
      "sid" : "xYL8HTqwvNYGnHjemo6iKXmmdvF3",
      "time" : "17:07:43 &"
    },
    "12 Mar, 202213:57:24 &" : {
      "category" : "tShirts",
      "date" : "12 Mar, 2022",
      "description" : "A pair of male shirts",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecommerce-app-c7f6b.appspot.com/o/Product%20Images%2Fimage%3A1253912%20Mar%2C%20202213%3A57%3A24%20%26.jpg?alt=media&token=b4e4e265-17f6-44c9-a006-193750d34732",
      "pid" : "12 Mar, 202213:57:24 &",
      "price" : "10000",
      "productStatus" : "Approved",
      "product_name" : "Male shirt",
      "sellerAddress" : "New Airport",
      "sellerEmail" : "elijah@gmail.com",
      "sellerName" : "Elijah Ukeme",
      "sellerPhone" : "08167988220",
      "sid" : "xYL8HTqwvNYGnHjemo6iKXmmdvF3",
      "time" : "13:57:24 &"
    },
    "12 Mar, 202213:59:34 &" : {
      "category" : "sweaters",
      "date" : "12 Mar, 2022",
      "description" : "Red color suite",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecommerce-app-c7f6b.appspot.com/o/Product%20Images%2Fimage%3A1254212%20Mar%2C%20202213%3A59%3A34%20%26.jpg?alt=media&token=1a84d781-d256-4d7c-bff3-4a20a7041726",
      "pid" : "12 Mar, 202213:59:34 &",
      "price" : "20000",
      "productStatus" : "Approved",
      "product_name" : "Male Suite",
      "sellerAddress" : "New Airport",
      "sellerEmail" : "elijah@gmail.com",
      "sellerName" : "Elijah Ukeme",
      "sellerPhone" : "08167988220",
      "sid" : "xYL8HTqwvNYGnHjemo6iKXmmdvF3",
      "time" : "13:59:34 &"
    },
    "12 Mar, 202214:01:56 &" : {
      "category" : "watches",
      "date" : "12 Mar, 2022",
      "description" : "Caret Gold Wristwatch",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecommerce-app-c7f6b.appspot.com/o/Product%20Images%2Fimage%3A1254012%20Mar%2C%20202214%3A01%3A56%20%26.jpg?alt=media&token=2b6e8132-a627-4192-ad91-27b22b0ab869",
      "pid" : "12 Mar, 202214:01:56 &",
      "price" : "5000",
      "productStatus" : "Approved",
      "product_name" : "Wristwatch",
      "sellerAddress" : "New Airport",
      "sellerEmail" : "elijah@gmail.com",
      "sellerName" : "Elijah Ukeme",
      "sellerPhone" : "08167988220",
      "sid" : "xYL8HTqwvNYGnHjemo6iKXmmdvF3",
      "time" : "14:01:56 &"
    },
    "12 Mar, 202214:04:16 &" : {
      "category" : "headSets",
      "date" : "12 Mar, 2022",
      "description" : "Red color Earphone",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecommerce-app-c7f6b.appspot.com/o/Product%20Images%2Fimage%3A1456112%20Mar%2C%20202214%3A04%3A16%20%26.jpg?alt=media&token=d6329856-a254-4a4d-bc85-89948d3cfe85",
      "pid" : "12 Mar, 202214:04:16 &",
      "price" : "2000",
      "productStatus" : "Approved",
      "product_name" : "Headset",
      "sellerAddress" : "New Airport",
      "sellerEmail" : "elijah@gmail.com",
      "sellerName" : "Elijah Ukeme",
      "sellerPhone" : "08167988220",
      "sid" : "xYL8HTqwvNYGnHjemo6iKXmmdvF3",
      "time" : "14:04:16 &"
    },
    "12 Mar, 202214:05:15 &" : {
      "category" : "bags",
      "date" : "12 Mar, 2022",
      "description" : "Female travelling bag",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecommerce-app-c7f6b.appspot.com/o/Product%20Images%2Fimage%3A1456012%20Mar%2C%20202214%3A05%3A15%20%26.jpg?alt=media&token=687a72c6-79a2-4660-b8e6-72792bdae25d",
      "pid" : "12 Mar, 202214:05:15 &",
      "price" : "3000",
      "productStatus" : "Approved",
      "product_name" : "Female bag",
      "sellerAddress" : "New Airport",
      "sellerEmail" : "elijah@gmail.com",
      "sellerName" : "Elijah Ukeme",
      "sellerPhone" : "08167988220",
      "sid" : "xYL8HTqwvNYGnHjemo6iKXmmdvF3",
      "time" : "14:05:15 &"
    },
    "12 Mar, 202214:06:29 &" : {
      "category" : "labtops",
      "date" : "12 Mar, 2022",
      "description" : "Mac pro laptop",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecommerce-app-c7f6b.appspot.com/o/Product%20Images%2Fimage%3A1455612%20Mar%2C%20202214%3A06%3A29%20%26.jpg?alt=media&token=8797d54a-e0c9-48d4-bc95-aac5c9eb104a",
      "pid" : "12 Mar, 202214:06:29 &",
      "price" : "50000",
      "productStatus" : "Approved",
      "product_name" : "Laptop",
      "sellerAddress" : "New Airport",
      "sellerEmail" : "elijah@gmail.com",
      "sellerName" : "Elijah Ukeme",
      "sellerPhone" : "08167988220",
      "sid" : "xYL8HTqwvNYGnHjemo6iKXmmdvF3",
      "time" : "14:06:29 &"
    },
    "12 Mar, 202214:07:20 &" : {
      "category" : "labtops",
      "date" : "12 Mar, 2022",
      "description" : "Apple laptop",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecommerce-app-c7f6b.appspot.com/o/Product%20Images%2Fimage%3A1455312%20Mar%2C%20202214%3A07%3A20%20%26.jpg?alt=media&token=a5bff715-b980-4b0b-a410-8024b8b7ab01",
      "pid" : "12 Mar, 202214:07:20 &",
      "price" : "100000",
      "productStatus" : "Approved",
      "product_name" : "Laptop",
      "sellerAddress" : "New Airport",
      "sellerEmail" : "elijah@gmail.com",
      "sellerName" : "Elijah Ukeme",
      "sellerPhone" : "08167988220",
      "sid" : "xYL8HTqwvNYGnHjemo6iKXmmdvF3",
      "time" : "14:07:20 &"
    },
    "12 Mar, 202214:08:23 &" : {
      "category" : "labtops",
      "date" : "12 Mar, 2022",
      "description" : "Elite Book laptop",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecommerce-app-c7f6b.appspot.com/o/Product%20Images%2Fimage%3A1455412%20Mar%2C%20202214%3A08%3A23%20%26.jpg?alt=media&token=dd080da9-bb33-4934-8c8d-e3708bfbed0b",
      "pid" : "12 Mar, 202214:08:23 &",
      "price" : "30000",
      "productStatus" : "Approved",
      "product_name" : "Laptop",
      "sellerAddress" : "New Airport",
      "sellerEmail" : "elijah@gmail.com",
      "sellerName" : "Elijah Ukeme",
      "sellerPhone" : "08167988220",
      "sid" : "xYL8HTqwvNYGnHjemo6iKXmmdvF3",
      "time" : "14:08:23 &"
    }
  },
  "Users" : {
    "08167988220" : {
      "Security Questions" : {
        "question1" : "Pounded yam",
        "question2" : "Madrid"
      },
      "address" : "New Airport, Calabar South",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecommerce-app-c7f6b.appspot.com/o/Profile%20Pictures%2F08167988220.jpg?alt=media&token=46998a82-815e-49f6-8299-cf507aa3b55c",
      "name" : "Elijah Ukeme",
      "password" : "meteorologist",
      "phone" : "08167988220",
      "phoneOrder" : "08167988220"
    }
  },
  "sellers" : {
    "xYL8HTqwvNYGnHjemo6iKXmmdvF3" : {
      "address" : "New Airport",
      "email" : "elijah@gmail.com",
      "name" : "Elijah Ukeme",
      "password" : "22446688",
      "phone" : "08167988220",
      "sid" : "xYL8HTqwvNYGnHjemo6iKXmmdvF3"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please indicate what is the **exact** code that produces that error. Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: the error is from that firebaseRecyclerAdapter, I am getting an error that says com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type model.DeliveredOrder @AlexMamo

Comment: At which line of code? Please also check the question in the second part of my comment.

Comment: The logcat is not indicating the line that the issue is coming from but I know that it is from that onStart() that I have the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter which has my model and viewmodel classes

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to show this reference in a `RecyclerView`:

```
deliveredOrderRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Delivered List");
```

The `Delivered List` node in your database looks like this:

```
"Delivered List" : {
  "address" : "New Airport",
  "city" : "Calabar",
  "deliveredDate" : "14 Mar, 2022",
  "deliveredTime" : "13:11:15 ",
  "name" : "Elijah Ukeme",
  "orderedDate" : "12 Mar, 2022",
  "orderedTime" : "14:14:29 ",
  "phone" : "08167988220",
  "receiversName" : "Joy Elijah",
  "totalAmount" : "15000"
},
```

So while it may be called a List, it actually only contains the property of a single order, which means that you can't show that as a list of orders in a recycler view. What happens is that FirebaseUI tries to parse each property (so `address`, `city`, etc) as an `Order`, which of course fails (as `"New Airport"` is not enough information to create an `Order` from) and that's what the error then shows.

---

If you want to show the current data, you can use this trick to load the same as a list of one order:

```
deliveredOrderRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().orderByKey().equalTo("Delivered List");
```

But the proper solution is to make the data under `Delivered List` into a real list, so:

```
"Delivered List" : {
  "key of first delivered order": {
    "address" : "New Airport",
    "city" : "Calabar",
    "deliveredDate" : "14 Mar, 2022",
    "deliveredTime" : "13:11:15 ",
    "name" : "Elijah Ukeme",
    "orderedDate" : "12 Mar, 2022",
    "orderedTime" : "14:14:29 ",
    "phone" : "08167988220",
    "receiversName" : "Joy Elijah",
    "totalAmount" : "15000"
  },
  "key of second delivered order": {
    "address" : "Another Airport",
    "city" : "Calabar",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thumps up to you, I added another child after the delivered List before saving the data and it works